# Не работает border-radius со значениями 20px/50px 20px/50px 0 0

Tags: css3, html, вёрстка, css

Требуется сделать блок у которого скурглены только два верхних угла. Скруглены не равномерно. Скажем 20px по горизонтали, 50 по вертикали. В таком случае эти значения задаются через слэш.

**Работает:** неравномерное скргуление для всех углов сразу:

```
border-radius: 20px/50px;
```

**Не работает:** неравномерное скргуление верхних углов в общей записи:

```
border-radius: 20px/50px 20px/50px 0 0;
```

**Не работает:** неравномерное скргуление верхних углов в индивидуальной для каждого записи:

```
border-top-left-radius: 20px/50px;
border-top-right-radius: 20px/50px;
```

[**набросок на jsFiddel**](http://jsfiddle.net/YU5dv/)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: [Исправленный набросок](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/YU5dv/2/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас неправильный синтаксис.

Правильный вот так: `[ <length> | <percentage> ]{1,4} [ / [ <length> | <percentage> ]{1,4} ]?` ([W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius)).

Результат (для наглядности увеличил):

```css
div, p, span {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background: purple;
    margin: 20px;
    display: block;    
}

div {
    border-radius: 40px 40px 0 0 / 100px 100px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо :)